# Prevent Arrays as Field Names in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, html, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 2.xx, I found out that on passing **Arrays as Field Names** in the html form it throws php and database errors. This is a serious vulnerability and what if an user does the same using chrome html debugging tool? It can cause security breach in the website! So, I was looking for a method to turn off the acceptance of Arrays as Field Names in codeigniter by default, but couldn't find it anywhere!

Is there any workaround with the core functionality so that form_validation, set_value() function and database drivers won't accept an array from the field name unless it is programmed for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys I didn't get any response for my question, So I came up with a work around. I made this small function which may get rid of input array injection.

1) Create a library file or a model. import it into the controller you wish to conduct this validation.

2) paste the following code into the model or library you just made:

```
    /*
 * Description: Checks for the array attacks in the input forms.
 * @param $allowedArrayInputs, the input field name which may contain array values
 * @param $method, post, get or request.
 * @return boolean, in case no conflicts is detected else invoke error.
 * */
public function array_inputs ($allowedArrayInputs = array (), $method = 'post') {
    if ($method == 'request') {
        $method_param = $_REQUEST;
    }
    elseif ($method == 'get') {
        $method_param = $_GET;
    }
    else {
        $method_param = $_POST;
    }
    foreach ($method_param as $key => $val2) {
        if (is_array($val2)) {
            if ($allowedArrayInputs && is_array($allowedArrayInputs)) {
                if (in_array($key, array ( 'confirm_password' ))) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            show_error('User input was invalid. Try again!');
            exit;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps someone who is facing this similar problem!

Good day to all!